# Unable to see connect device to Android Studio for debugging

Tags: android, debugging

I have a tablet with Android V6. I have enabled Developer Options and ticked 'enable USB debugging'. I have selected MTP in USB configurations, but my device is still not showing in the Select deployment Target box in Android Studio. (Device is showing in My Computer). The cable seems to be OK as it works with other devices. Googled the problem with no satisfactory result. can anyone assist?

Comment: You can try updating drivers [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)

Comment: thanks, but still not working.

Comment: Did you try PTP also!! sometime PTP also works.

Comment: Bingo - that works, thanks very much

Comment: Great, I should make this an answer and you can mark it so if anybody else getting problem may find this area useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can try updating drivers from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html)
2. Some mobile works on MTP and some on PTP, try using one.